# Java/C/C++/C#/PHP to Pascal converter?

Tags: java, c++, c, delphi, pascal

Does anyone know if there is a Java/C/C++/C#/PHP to Pascal converter?

Comment: Language conversion is VERY finicky thing.

Comment: @Dhaivat yes it is, extremely finicky. I remember converting C++ to Delphi one time and ran into huge problems with my program crashing because `@GetProcAddress` in Delphi isn't the same as `&GetProcAddress` in C++ (C++ takes the address of the function but Delphi takes the address of the _wrapper_ function for the real `GetProcAddress`.) *shiver*

Comment: It looks like community wiki candidate

Comment: Is this a "I want to cheat on my homework" question?

Comment: Maybe yes but it would be fine to make a list of that

Comment: @Robin maybe, as you cannot really use Pascal except for educational purposes (maybe Delphi makes some sense, but even that's more of a legend to me).

Comment: I don't think there is anyone who can write c/c++ code but can't write pascal code, but everyone has a right to make daft assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[H2Pas](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse40.html) is a popular tool to convert C headers to Pascal. I don't know of any to actually convert C code to Pascal code though.

From a quick google search, I see several that may or may not be good:

- http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/23991
- http://c2pas.sourceforge.net/

I am tempted to say you'll have to do a lot of it by hand one way or another.

Comment: Yeah, tried c2pas, but might as well write the program in pascal from scratch than use that. It may work for dead simple programs though.

Answer (score 1):

Java to Pascal converter:
http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/archive/index.php/t-4845.html

Comment: Obsolete. Link to java2delphi.jar is broken.

Answer (score 1):

C to Pascal converters:

1. http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26951
2. http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm
3. http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html
4. http://www.astonshell.com/freeware/c2pas32
5. http://www.cadkas.com/ec2delphi.php
6. http://c2pas.sourceforge.net
7. http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/H2Pas
8. http://wiki.freepascal.org/Chelper

Tips for conversion from C:

- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html
- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html
- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html
- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html
- http://www.awitness.org/delphi_pascal_tutorial/c++_delphi

Biggest time saver tip for header conversion from C is to find a VB header and convert it with VB converter mentioned in other answer. This was almost always fully automated and changes I had to make were none or minor!

Answer (score 0):

VB to Pascal converters:

1. http://www.marcocantu.com/tools/vb2delphi.htm
2. http://www.vbto.net

Answer (score 0):

There was released [Android2DelphiImport tool](http://journeyman.ath.cx/) a short time ago. This tool is designed for XE5, and automates the import unit writing by generating a pascal wrapper unit from jar. It is a commercial package.
Here are another two similar tools - [Utility to generate Java Android class and jar file interfaces for Delphi XE5 Firemonkey](http://www.fmxexpress.com/utility-to-generate-java-android-class-and-jar-file-interfaces-for-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/) ('JavaToPas' and 'JavaImport For Android').